# How to create an instance for this class based on the documentation?

Tags: java, reddit

This is the class documentation:
http://thatjavanerd.github.io/JRAW/docs/0.8.0/net/dean/jraw/http/UserAgent.html

I am trying to create an instance of UserAgent as below:

```
UserAgent ua = new UserAgent("/u/ohhemmgee fyp");
```

but Eclipse says the `constructor is not visible`.
What's wrong? And how should I go about to create the instance?

Comment: Did you go through the link you have given? Did you check the `of()` method (Which is static and returns an instance)?

Comment: There is no visible constructor. There are two static methods you can use, though.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the following static method :

> static UserAgent of(java.lang.String val)
>
> Instantiates a new UserAgent  with a custom value.

Like

```
UserAgent myUserAgent = UserAgent.of("myVal");
```

Comment: Wondering if you know why im getting this error:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dean/jraw/http/UserAgent

Comment: It looks like the JAR file containing class net/dean/jraw/http/UserAgent, is not on your classpath , you have to add it .

Comment: Added and got this new error: net.dean.jraw.http.NetworkException: Request returned non-successful status code: 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Use the static method [`of(String)`](http://thatjavanerd.github.io/JRAW/docs/0.8.0/net/dean/jraw/http/UserAgent.html#of(java.lang.String)) of the class to create a new instance:

```
UserAgent ua = UserAgent.of("/u/ohhemmgee fyp");
```

You cannot use the constructor directrly because it is private and therefore cannot be accessed from outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is indeed `private`. You can create a `UserAgent` instance with the static method [`of`](http://thatjavanerd.github.io/JRAW/docs/0.8.0/net/dean/jraw/http/UserAgent.html#of(java.lang.String)), though:

```
UserAgent ua = UserAgent.of("/u/ohhemmgee fyp");
```